# Wordpress JWT authentication Token Issue

Tags: wordpress, authentication, jwt, wordpress-rest-api

I'm Using JWT authentication plugin to wordpress rest api for api access authentication but the issue is `https://example.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token` is generating error that it is not allowing.

For example if i try to run this url in postman ``https://example.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token` this API also requires authentication where it is supposed to run smoothly with authentication.

So why this url API requires authentication and can't access this api without authentication is my concern.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution created one plugin and add below code in it works great.

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) { exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'require_auth_for_all_endpoints' ) ) {
    add_filter( 'rest_pre_dispatch', 'require_auth_for_all_endpoints', 10, 3 );
    function require_auth_for_all_endpoints( $result, $server, $request ) {
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {

            // Only allow these endpoints: JWT Auth.
            $allowed_endpoints = array(
                '/jwt-auth/v1/token/validate',
                '/jwt-auth/v1/token',
                '/oauth/authorize',
                '/oauth/token',
                '/oauth/me',
            );
            $allowed_endpoints = apply_filters( 'reqauth/allowed_endpoints', $allowed_endpoints );

            // Endpoint checker.
            $regex_checker = '#^(' . join( '|', $allowed_endpoints ) . ')#';
            $regex_checker = apply_filters( 'reqauth/regex_checker', $regex_checker );

            $is_allowed = preg_match( $regex_checker, $request->get_route() );
            $is_allowed = apply_filters( 'reqauth/is_allowed', $is_allowed );

            if ( ! $is_allowed ) {
                return new WP_Error( 'rest_not_logged_in', __( 'You are not currently logged in.' ), array( 'status' => 401 ) );
            }
        }
    }
}
```